# Javascript rotate mouseover pause?

Tags: javascript, rotation, carousel, mouseover

I'm trying to modify a word dial, but am not much of a javascript pro(yet). How can I pause this dial on hover/mouseover within the existing code..................................................................................................................................................

html:

```
<h1>
  I feel like eating
    <ul class="word-rotate">  
      <li>chocolate</li> 
      <li>pizza</li>
      <li>chicken wings</li>
      <li>lobster</li>
      <li>cheesecake</li>
      <li>donuts</li>
      <li>coconut shrimp</li>
      <li>strawberry crepe</li>
    </ul>
</h1>
```

css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center; 
      align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
  background: #8E24AA;
  color: #fff;
}

.word-rotate {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 10em;
  height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.word-rotate li {
  height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

js:

```
var wr = document.querySelector(".word-rotate");

var words = wr.children;

var x = 0;
rotate(x);

setInterval(function () {
  x = ++x % words.length;
  rotate(x);
}, 1000);

function rotate(start) {
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
    var j = (start + i) % words.length;
    var percent = j / words.length;
    var rad = percent * 2 * Math.PI;
    var ty = Math.sin(rad) * 200;
    var tz = 40 * Math.cos(rad) - 40;
    var op = (Math.cos(rad) + 1) / 2;
    words[i].style.transform = "perspective(100px) translateZ(" + tz + "px) translateY(" + ty + "%)";
    words[i].style.opacity = "" + op;
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like we need more code - this is just an unordered list (what is a dial?) Maybe some css and script will help demonstrate your question

Comment: Take a few minutes to read [ask] and [mcve]. That html alone does nothing other than display a list

Comment: Sorry guys, I hadn't read how to properly format the question/code, so most was accidentally left out. How about now?

Comment: Am I being punished for not using correct formatting from start lol? :(

Comment: Not being punished, most people only look at the newest questions and give up easily :)  This is actually really cool looking

Comment: Another tip - you can use @ + [name] so they get an alert, I didn't know you edited your question until I stumbled across it again. (ex. @IrkenInvader)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events, then set a flag (true on enter, false on exit) that will pause the scrolling.

```
var pauseRotate = false;

wr.onmouseover = function() {
  pauseRotate = true;
}

wr.onmouseout = function() {
   pauseRotate = false;
}
```

In your `setInterval` function, check first to see if `pauseRotate` is true, if it is we can return without doing anything.

```
setInterval(function () {
  if(pauseRotate) return;
  x = ++x % words.length;
  rotate(x);
}, 1000);
```

```js
var wr = document.querySelector(".word-rotate");

var words = wr.children;
var pauseRotate = false;

var x = 0;
rotate(x);

wr.onmouseover = function() {
  pauseRotate = true;
}

wr.onmouseout = function() {
  pauseRotate = false;
}

setInterval(function () {
  if(pauseRotate) return;
  x = ++x % words.length;
  rotate(x);
}, 1000);

function rotate(start) {
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
    var j = (start + i) % words.length;
    var percent = j / words.length;
    var rad = percent * 2 * Math.PI;
    var ty = Math.sin(rad) * 200;
    var tz = 40 * Math.cos(rad) - 40;
    var op = (Math.cos(rad) + 1) / 2;
    words[i].style.transform = "perspective(100px) translateZ(" + tz + "px) translateY(" + ty + "%)";
    words[i].style.opacity = "" + op;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center; 
      align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
  background: #8E24AA;
  color: #fff;
}

.word-rotate {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 10em;
  height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.word-rotate li {
  height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  I feel like eating
    <ul class="word-rotate">  
      <li>chocolate</li> 
      <li>pizza</li>
      <li>chicken wings</li>
      <li>lobster</li>
      <li>cheesecake</li>
      <li>donuts</li>
      <li>coconut shrimp</li>
      <li>strawberry crepe</li>
    </ul>
</h1>
```